# Method Call and Setter Injection in Model/Non-Controller Class

Tags: php, symfony

## Plea

I have read the "Service Container" entry--and nearly every linked entry--in the Symfony 4 docs. I have tackled this issue on two separate occasions spending 4-6 hours each time. I clearly just don't get it...please help!

## Want

I want to use dependency injection to use a service (SessionInterface) in a model (User) but I do not want to use the model constructor as then I would need to inject the dependency each time I hydrate and instantiate the model. I think I should be able to use method call and setter injection to meet this criteria.

## Code

### services.yaml

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

### Model

```
namespace App\Model\System\User;

use App\Model\System\Client\Client;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\{EquatableInterface, UserInterface};

class User implements EquatableInterface, UserInterface
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(array $properties)
    {
        // stuff
    }

    public function clientAssumed(): Client
    {
        return $this->session->get('foo', 'bar');
    }

    /**
     * @required
     *
     * @param SessionInterface $session
     */
    public function setSession(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
namespace App\Controller\Core;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class CoreBase extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * Displays authenticated User landing page.
     *
     * @Route("/home", name="core_home")
     *
     * @param Security $security
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function landing(Security $security): Response
    {
        $data = [
            'client' => $security->getUser()->clientAssumed(),
        ];

        return $this->render('core/landing.html.twig', $data);
    }
}
```

### Service Information

```
php bin/console debug:container 'App\Model\System\User\User'
```

.

```
Information for Service "App\Model\System\User\User"
====================================================

 ---------------- ---------------------------- 
  Option           Value                       
 ---------------- ---------------------------- 
  Service ID       App\Model\System\User\User  
  Class            App\Model\System\User\User  
  Tags             -                           
  Calls            setSession                  
  Public           no                          
  Synthetic        no                          
  Lazy             no                          
  Shared           yes                         
  Abstract         no                          
  Autowired        yes                         
  Autoconfigured   yes                         
 ---------------- ----------------------------
```

## Result

```
Too few arguments to function App\Model\System\User\User::setSession(), 0 passed in /srv/http/wwwroot/gw4/src/Controller/Core/CoreBase.php on line 25 and exactly 1 expected
```

Comment: the last example on https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html seems to indicate you have to add the user model to services yaml and add the parameter as in the example ... have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, if I understand what you are referring to I have tried that. It produced the same result as I have autowiring on and '@required' on the method.

Comment: your error message suggests that setSession doesn't get any parameters. and the yaml version seemed pretty explicit when it comes to the parameters.

Comment: User is an entity, not a service.  Makes no sense to try and inject dependencies into it.  You need some sort of user manager service with UserManager::clientAssumed($user);

Comment: TY for your response. Please help me to understand better. Say I want to get a list of groups a user is member of. Currently I would add a "groups" method to my user model. Would you suggest adding the methods to the UserManager service instead? What is the suggested design pattern called?

Comment: If your User entity has a groups property then User::getGroups() is fine.  In your question you have User::clientAssumed().  I don't know what that means but it appears that it requires access to the session instead of just an internal property of some sort.  If external dependencies are needed (which should be avoided) then a  independent service class is called for. Or maybe User::clientAssumed($session).  In general, Doctrine entities should only know about other Doctrine entities.

Comment: I have changed 'clientAssumed' to a property which is set when instantiating the User object. As far as my 'groups' example I think a good approach would be to use the repository pattern passing the User as a a parameter (eg. GroupRepository->fetchByUser($user)). Thank you for your explanations.